# Repeater ItemDataBound NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am getting a `NullReferenceException` when there is a null value in my data. There will be many null and empty values in this data and I want to highlight them. col2 is the id of the td

```
<td id="col2"><asp:Label ID="ESubject" Text='<%# (Eval("EventSubject") == null) ? "null" : Eval("EventSubject") %>' runat="server" /></td>
```

```
protected void myRepeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    { 
            var varSubject = e.Item.FindControl("ESubject");
            var adjSubject = varSubject.ToString();

            HtmlTableCell td = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("col2");

            if (adjSubject == "null")
            {
                td.BgColor = "yellow";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably tag this with `asp.net` and any other relevant tags.

Comment: @Sach Yes I was in the process of editing the question

Comment: I think you need to tell it what to expect. It is a label after all. Text='  <%# ((string)Eval("EventSubject") == null) ? "" : Eval("EventSubject") %>' something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `runat="server"` if you want to access a regular html control from code-behind.

```
<td id="col2" runat="server">
   ...
</td>
```

We use `.FindControl` if you want to find a child control.

Since `HtmlTableCell` is a *immediate* parent of the label control, you need to use `.Parent`.

```
protected void myRepeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var varSubject = e.Item.FindControl("ESubject");
        var adjSubject = varSubject.Parent as HtmlTableCell;
        if (adjSubject != null)
        {
            adjSubject.BgColor = "yellow";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works but it highlights all cells, including cells that have text. How would only highlight null and empty cells?

Comment: Depending on data source, you'll need to cast `e.Item.DataItem` to appropriate type like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples). Then get the value of `ESubject`.

Comment: Yes Thank you Win. The issue was with the way my SQL Statement was constructed than the ItemDataBound.